# A pixijs question: Are filters run on each of the sprites within a container or on the container as a unit

Tags: pixi.js

I have made a custom filter. It darkens a sprite from right to left. I would like to apply the filter to a container, containing multiple sprites, so that the sprites to the left would be more dark than the sprites to the right. However, this is not the case. It seems that the filter is applied to each of the sprites separately within the container. Do anyone know if this is standard behaviour for a pixijs container?

I used the latest version of pixijs, version 7.2.0.

Regards, Benjamin